# ACQ Json to Java models conversion

Tags: amadeus

I want to convert an already existing Request / Response models with full fiels just to make sure not to be missing any Data when I'm testing and making Scenarios to get Certificate.

I'm creating models of each Request / Response of each service based on the examples of the documentation , now trying to get certification I found out that the models that I converted from Json to Java classes can be missing Important data based on Test Scenario , is there a link where I can find a full completed models with any form that I can reverse to Java instead of going to documentation and exploring the model Tree option of each Request  to find out what fields that I'm missing and adding it to my Java classes.

Answer (score 1):

By importing a swagger api spec file (can be downloaded from the documentation) in https://editor.swagger.io/(this website is not the only tool) a client/server reversed project can be generated which contains all the models needed for each api